# How to calculate shares in Quipuswap V2 dex?

Tags: smart-contracts, dex

In [quipuswap dex v2](https://github.com/madfish-solutions/quipuswap-webapp-2), when we call invest_liquidity, there is parameter called shares. I want to know how to calculate those shares.

I know that there is view in contract called get_toks_per_share but it gives 2 values token_a_amt and token_b_amt.

If this values are used to calculate shares then is there any formula to calculate the shares using this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have an `amount_a` of the token a and `amount_b` of token b, you want to invest.

1. Call the view `get_total_supply` to get the current supply of shares.
2. Call the view to get the reserves `get_reserves`, you will receive `reserves_a` anount of token a and  `reserves_b` of token b in the pool .
3. Then calculate the shares required:

```
    shares_a = amount_a * total_supply / reserves_a
    shares_b = amount_b * total_supply / reserves_b
```

Then calculate min (shares_a, shares_b) and it will be the answer.

But note: if shares_a =/= shares_b, then the smaller amount of one of the tokens will be used. if shares_a > shares_b, then smaller amount of token a will be invested than you wanted and versa versa.